# How to upgrade kernel on Pinebook now ARM support is mainlined?

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, compiling, arm

I have a [Pinebook](https://www.pine64.org/pinebook/) with a [Quad-Core ARM Cortex A53 64-Bit CPU](https://developer.arm.com/ip-products/processors/cortex-a/cortex-a53) running the official KDE Neon image with the really old official 3.10 kernel. In 4.17 support for the Pinebook was mainlined, so technically I should be able to build the latest mainline kernel, package it as a deb and install it, right?

However, I can only find instructions on how to do that with x86 based machines. Where do I start if I want to do that on my ARM Pinebook?

Comment: Can you include the output of `sudo modprobe configs; ls /proc/config.gz`?

Comment: It would also be good to include the instructions you found for x86 machines.

Comment: Sure, but you can just Google "compile kernel" and you will be mostly set, for example: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be images for arm using later kernels, I went through installing them - but I have a feeling that they do not install properly and threw errors on installation so I backed them out before trying them.
You can ignore the "helpful" advice on compiling kernels as that won't solve the main issue, which is working out on how to install it etc.
There are tools:
https://github.com/ayufan-pine64/linux-build/releases
But I haven't had the time to go through on how to use them, and I haven't found any decent instructions on how to do it end-to-end.
I have limited time to do research, so that could be my fault.
I thought there would be instructions out there to do it, or an already updated kernel as the current kernel has issues and the new kernels work faster and better.

You can try manjaro linux on an sd card,it has a newer kernel, so you can at least see the difference.